# SQL Access " Count "?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
table

Name  tap
aa     1
aa     1
aa     2
bb     2
aa     3
cc     1
bb     2
bb     3
cc     2
```

Results ?????

```
name  Count(1)   Count(2)   Count(3)
aa      2           1          1
bb      0           2          1
cc      1           1          0
```

??????

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're showing us what looks like your data and what you want a query to produce, but you haven't asked a question. Have you written a query? Are you having problems getting this specific result? Also, read [ask] for some helpful hints on how to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use *Count* as it will do just that - count the number of records for each *Name* ignoring the value of *tap*.

But you check for the values of *tap* and sum these matches. However, while *SQL Server* returns 1 for a match, *Access* returns -1, thus - for a universal solution - you can apply *Abs* to always have a positive sum.

Then you get a query like this:

```
Select
    [Name],
    Abs(Sum(tap=1)) As Count1,
    Abs(Sum(tap=2)) As Count2,
    Abs(Sum(tap=3)) As Count3
From
    YourTable
Group By
    [Name]
```

Output will be:

```
Name  Count1  Count2  Count3
aa         2       1       1
bb         0       2       1
cc         1       1       0
```

Comment: Interesting. A downvote for a correct answer. Happy Easter!

Comment: I guess your answer is experiencing the dispute over [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions) .

Comment: I downvoted this answer for two reasons - the first being that this is a code-only answer, and the second being that the asker quite literally *did not ask a question*.

Comment: @Sculper: OK, that's a valid point, though I believe an obtuse question expects an obtuse answer. Explanation added.

Comment: @Andre: Yes, that discussion covers it. I noted that the top votes goes to: "Answers should be voted up or down on their own merits." which seems not to be the case here, rather "while users don't engage in vote fraud, they can vote whichever way they want.". Normally I just refrain from dealing with "bad" questions, but - while _implicit_ - this question was quite clear to me, _and_ the questioneer is new, I saw no reason to not provide a proper answer.